# Error de cors en una peticion ionic a web api

Tags: c#, ionic, webapi

Tengo una app ionic que hago una petición a una api webapi desarrollada en c# así:

```
api_url="https://misitio.com.ar/sitio"    
var token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX2lub0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1laWQiOiIyIiwicm9sZSI6IlZlY2lubyIsIm5iZiI6MTYxMDU0OTQzNCwiZXhwIjoxNjE4MzI1NDM0LCJpYXQiOjE2MTA1NDk0MzUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmJlcmF6YXRlZ3VpLmdvdi5hciJ9.TY8QnuOVVyckQ0c-hkwHLdzZOBugSxCgaJ-LZiVgNis";   



const mheaders = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }
  const body = { 
  }
     return this._http.post<any>(`${this.api_url}/api/Lugar/buscar`, lugar,{headers : mheaders});      
  }
```

Luego en la web api c# tengo el siguiente codigo en el WebApiConfig

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Esto, si lo ejecuto en localhost, osea con el visual studio corriendo, y en el navegador, funciona bien, pero si lo publico en el servidor, siempre da error de cors.
Otro dato es que tambien tengo una app en angular en ese servidor y se conecta bien a la api, no da error de cors, pero la app ionic si.
El error que da el android studio cuando debuggeo la ap es:
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/tabs/tab1 - Line 0 - Msg: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://misitio.com.ar/sitio/api/Lugar/buscar' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

si es en netcore, debes agregar el servicio para habilitar los cors primero y despues en configure

en services agrega esto

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("corsAPP", builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().
                        AllowAnyMethod().
                        AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

en configure habilita el cors

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
        app.UseCors("corsAPP");
}
```

Comment: No, no es Net Core

Comment: Entonces solo agrega el método `config.EnableCors()`, debes instalar este paquete `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` aquí la documentación te da los pasos `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api`

Answer (score 0):

AL final lo resolví colocando en el web_config

```
<system.webServer>

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Así funciona, pero no se cuan seguro es, la api esta muy descubierta supongo, estaría bueno poder habilitar los cors para un solo controlador por ejemplo, que es el que es llamado desde la app móvil, eso nunca lo vi, no se si se podrá hacer...