# Redsys modalidad InSite con elementos independientes

Tags: jquery, rest

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo con ASP.Net Core (Razor pages) y me encuentro en el último paso de la integración de la pasarela redsys con la modalidad InSite con integración de elementos independientes; trabajando en el entorno de pruebas.

[En la guía de integración InSite](https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-insite.html), en el paso 5, se indica: "El comercio lanza la operación de pago mediante una [conexión REST"](https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-rest.html). El enlace lleva a la guía de integración REST.

Siguiendo todos los pasos de esta guía se obtiene el mensaje que hay que enviar a la api REST, en mi caso a la de pruebas https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/rest/trataPeticionREST

El resultado de JSON.stringify(dataRest) es:

{**"Ds_MerchantParameters"**:"eyJEU19NRVJDSEFOVF9BTU9VTlQiOiI3Myw4NCIsIkRTX01FUkNIQU5UX0NVUlJFTkNZIjoiOTc4IiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfTUVSQ0hBTlRDT0RFIjoiMzUyNDM0NDM1IiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfT1JERVIiOiIwMDAwMDAwMDA3NjUiLCJEU19NRVJDSEFOVF9JRE9QRVIiOiIxODExNzViOTBjNDM2ZDNlZDQ3ODg4OWEyMjdjNjI2Yjc0MDBiOTEyIiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfVEVSTUlOQUwiOiIxIiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfVFJBTlNBQ1RJT05UWVBFIjoiMCJ9",**"Ds_Signature"**:"X5IoP/ssIy+8gBFbD9znLoz4dFOH/mWRjMCaE/8kq65XJJVLywT05wVXE4Fqbbo6",**"Ds_SignatureVersion"**:"HMAC_SHA256_V1"}

Lo estoy haciendo con Jquery Ajax y todas las veces me sale error 405 Method Not Allowed. Lo he intentado con GET y POST, pero es igual.

Este es el código ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/rest/trataPeticionREST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: JSON.stringify(dataRest)
}).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).fail(function (error) {
  console.error(error.status + '\n' + error.responseText);
});
```

**dataType: 'jsonp'** es para evitar que salga el siguiente error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/rest/trataPeticionREST' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxx.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda si alguien ha conseguido este tipo de integración.

**Nota:** Cuando termine la integración postearé todo el código (html, js y c#), ya que casi todo lo que se encuentra de redsys es sobre la integración con redirección, respecto a la integración InSite no hay nada, lo que se encuentra es con CMS's, pero no con programación a medida, valga decirlo, las guías de Redsys son bastante malas y no incluyen ningún ejemplo completo. El único ejemplo (bastante malo) es el que llega hasta obtener el id de operación.

Comment: El problema no es jQuery, el problema está en la API con la que te comunicas, tienes que permitir el acceso. Lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/423010/822 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/218426/822

Comment: Efectivamente, para poder llamar a la api tengo que hacerlo del lado del servidor para que reconozca el origen.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando tengas funcionando el método, agrega la respuesta en la parte inferior de la pregunta. Saludos.